# TypeError: message.channel.forEach is not a function

Tags: node.js, foreach

I have a problem, I created a function for sending a message in a discord channel.

I already tried to replace `foreach` to `forEach` but, it doesn't work.

```
setInterval (function () { message.channel.forEach(); message.channel.send("@everyone blah test", { tts: true } ).catch(error => {}) }, 400)
```

I got this error:

> TypeError: message.channel.forEach is not a function

Can someone please help me? This will be nice and will help to explain what did I do wrong.

Comment: try logging `message.channel` and tell us if it's an Array

Comment: i solved my error i just delete ```message.channel.forEach();``` which was just too much ```message.channel``` works with specific value of the discord.js package thx anyway